# How do I read exactly one char from a Stream?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Stream with some text data (can be ASCII, UTF-8, Unicode; encoding is known). I need to read exactly one char from the stream, without advancing stream position any longer. StreamReader is inappropriate, as it aggressively prefetches data from the stream.
Ideas?

Comment: BinaryReader.ReadChar ?

Comment: If you don't know or specify the encoding, a char may be one or more bytes. That's why the StreamReader reads ahead, to detect the encoding. It also contains a character buffer that is filled when reading. Can you provide your own StreamReader or show the relevant code for when the indicated issue occurs?

Comment: @CodeCaster, StreamReader reads ahead much further than necessary to read 1 char. That's why I can't use it.

Comment: Steamreader has a buffer size, did you tried set it to '1' so it will only read 1 char to the buffer?

Comment: @Ziv [_"If bufferSize is less than the minimum allowable size (128 characters), the minimum allowable size is used"_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143458(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: hmm, maybe this will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520722/unbuffered-streamreader

Comment: What's the encoding? If it's ASCII `stream.ReadByte()` will do the job (if it's positive just cast it to `char`).

Comment: @Alex K., BinaryReader.ReadChar seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Alex K., why don't make this an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read and decode the text one byte at a time, the most convenient approach I know of is to use the System.Text.Decoder class.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

        string originalText = "Hello world! ブ䥺ぎょズィ穃 槞こ廤樊稧 ひゃご禺 壪";
        byte[] rgb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalText);
        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(rgb);
        string result = DecodeOneByteAtATimeFromStream(dataStream);

        Console.WriteLine("Result string: \"" + result + "\"");
        if (originalText == result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Original and result strings are equal");
        }
    }

    static string DecodeOneByteAtATimeFromStream(MemoryStream dataStream)
    {
        Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int inputByteCount;
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[1];

        while ((inputByteCount = dataStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, 1)) > 0)
        {
            int charCount = decoder.GetCharCount(inputBuffer, 0, 1);
            char[] rgch = new char[charCount];

            decoder.GetChars(inputBuffer, 0, 1, rgch, 0);
            sb.Append(rgch);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Presumably you are already aware of the drawbacks of processing data of any sort just one byte at a time. :) Suffice to say, this is not a very efficient way to do things.