# C# partial UTF-8 byte stream conversion

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

I have wrote the following simple test:

```
[Test]
public void TestUTF8()
{
    var c = "abc☰def";
    var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c);

    Assert.That(b.Length, Is.EqualTo(9));
    //Assuming, you are reading a byte stream and got partial result with the first 5 bytes
    var p = Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(b, 0, 5);
    Trace.WriteLine(new string(p));
    Assert.That(p.Length, Is.EqualTo(3));
}
```

The `Trace` outputs `abc�` and the last assert fails because `p.Length` is `4`.

However, I wanted `Trace` outputs `abc` and the last assert passes, since in reality I know the stream will have valid chars and when it is not the case for the last few bytes, just leave them there waiting for more data to come.

So how can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: I believe this is just how `GetChars` works. It designed for complete input. If you are decoding a stream it is recommended that you use `Decoder.Convert` over `GetChars` for this exact reason. A decoder is obtained from `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder` in this case.

Comment: You are right... Using `GetChars` is just because it is simple... So if we have to use more complicated functions it is fine. Can you provide an answer with this suggestion?

Comment: @EarthEngine: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844999/how-do-i-read-exactly-one-char-from-a-stream/26851980#26851980  The OP there seems to have settled on using `BinaryReader` (which is actually probably just as well, given they wanted to just read a single character at a time), but my answer shows how to implement that behavior at a less-abstract level, and can be easily adapted to read buffers of arbitrary length at a time.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Good call. `Decoder.GetChars` seems to be somewhat easier to use. I've expanded your sample to an arbitrary buffer size in my answer.

Comment: @EarthEngine Ok, I've got an answer based on `Decoder.GetChars` which is slightly easier to use than `Decoder.Convert`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Encoding.GetChars` isn't really designed for bytes coming from a stream where some state needs to be kept track of during the decoding process because a single character might span multiple buffer segments. To do that work you should use a `Decoder` obtained from `Encoding.GetDecoder`. However, `Decoder.Convert` is really low-level allowing you control over both the input and output buffers and somewhat difficult to use. `Decoder.GetChars` is somewhat easier to use and does the important work of storing state between calls. We can easily expand on Peter Duniho's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26851980/517852) for arbitrary buffer size:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c = "abc☰def";
    var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c);
    var result = DecodeFromStream(new MemoryStream(b), Encoding.UTF8, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.WriteLine(c == result);
}

private static string DecodeFromStream(Stream dataStream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
{
    Decoder decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int inputByteCount;
    byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    char[] charBuffer = new char[encoding.GetMaxCharCount(inputBuffer.Length)];

    while ((inputByteCount = dataStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) > 0)
    {                   
       int readChars = decoder.GetChars(inputBuffer, 0, inputByteCount, charBuffer, 0);
       if (readChars > 0)
           sb.Append(charBuffer, 0, readChars);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```